# PHP: How to echo strings from an Array?

Tags: arrays, string, echo

I'm stuck trying to echo strings from an array, all I get is "Array" as text.

This is the array:

```
    $_SESSION['lista'][] = array(
'articulo' => $articulo, 
'precio' => $precio, 
'cantidad' => $cantidad);
```

This is the echo:

```
echo "1. ".$_SESSION['lista'][0][0]." ".$_SESSION['lista'][0][1]." unidades".", ".$_SESSION['lista'][0][2]." CRC.";
```

The current output is:

```
1. Array Array unidades, Array CRC.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [] so it looks like these
And put session_start() at starting line;

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lista'] = array(
'articulo' => $articulo, 
'precio' => $precio, 
'cantidad' => $cantidad);
?>
```

To access the array:

```
echo $_SESSION['lista']['articulo'];

echo $_SESSION['lista']['precio'];
```

Comment: Thanks, the extra [] was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an associative array member with a numerical key as an offset.

Try this...

```
echo $_SESSION['lista'][0]['articulo'];
```

An `array`'s *to string* type method is called (and returns `Array`) when you try to implicitly convert it to a string, e.g. with `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) along with var_dump etc. As stated in the manual, these functions print the contents of arrays/objects in human readable format.